# C# - Verify List

Tags: c#

So I have this code to verify if the 4 colors (array "cores_dos_pontos_medios") appears 3 straight frames (from video feed). If it does I can do:

```
posicao = loc.Coordenadas(cores_dos_pontos_medios); //obtem as coordenadas atraves das cores
```

The problem is that it's not verifying correctly. It still sends cores_dos_pontos_medios to loc even tho it doesnt appear 3 times straight.

```
cores = cores_dos_pontos_medios[0] + " , " + cores_dos_pontos_medios[1] + " , " + cores_dos_pontos_medios[2] + " , " + cores_dos_pontos_medios[3];

int n_de_verificacoes_cores = 3;

if (lista_cores.Count >= n_de_verificacoes_cores)
{
    lista_cores.RemoveAt(0);
}
lista_cores.Add(cores);


if (lista_cores.Count >= n_de_verificacoes_cores && lista_cores.Any(s => s == lista_cores[0]))
{

    posicao = loc.Coordenadas(cores_dos_pontos_medios); //obtem as coordenadas atraves das cores
```

**EDIT: now that I think about it maybe I need to remove everything on the list lista_cores?**

Comment: why people always dislike my posts?

Comment: I would say it's because nobody can understand code written in non-english language?

Comment: there's only string cores,cores-pontos_medios string array and lista_cores is a list...

Comment: You know about the existence of http://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: I cannot help just because I dont understand anything. For me `posicao` is the same as you would call it `__321dsa321__`. It's mostly because you've never showed somethings like `int posicao = 0;` or something similiar. ( meaning the initialization of the field )

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `lista_cores.Any(s => s == lista_cores[0])` is always true because this instruction is checking if any of the element of lista_cores is equal to the first element of lista_cores.
If what you want to do is check if all elements are equal you have to use 
 `lista_cores.All(s => s == lista_cores[0])`

Comment: I wanted to compare if all the string on that list have the same text. If it does send it to class loc and do it again. Do I need to clear the list or just removeat(0)?

Comment: Well if you remove all elements you won't have nothing to compare so i don't think you have to remove them. The problem is in the if condition try sobstituting any with all

Answer (score 0):

From your "*I wanted to compare if all the string on that list have the same text*" comment I suppose you want something like this, but I didnt understand most of your question..

```
bool containsInvalidData = false;
foreach(string valueToCheck in lista_cores)
{
    if(lista_cores.Any(p => valueToCheck != p)) containsInvalidData = true;
    break;
}
```

You can also do it in a single call, using List.ForEach() function